# Is quotient by maximal destabilizing sheaf, torsion-free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $k$ be an infinite field (not necessarily algebraically closed), $X$ a smooth, projective curve over $k$ and $F$ a pure, coherent sheaf on $X$. Let $F'$ be the maximal destabilizing sheaf of $F$. Is the quotient sheaf $F/F'$ locally free?

Comment: If $k=\mathbb C$, then you can argue the following: as $F'$ is saturated in $F$ (saturation increases slope), $F/F'$ is torsion free, so it is locally free on an open subset whose complement has codimension at least two. In particular, if the base is a smooth curve, $F/F'$ is locally free. For a reference, see for instance Kobayashi, Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles, Corollary 5.15.

Comment: @Henri Thanks for the answer. I had a non-algebraically closed field in mind. I have specified it more clearly in the question now. Does the same argument still work for non-algebraically closed field? If I understand corrently, the Serre's conditions on normality is not preserved under base change, meaning isn't it possible that the quotient is torsion-free on $X$ but not geometrically torsion-free?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as geometrically (non-)torsion-free.